# ViewModel instance - Activity UI - Android Architecture Components

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

```
 public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private WordRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

    public WordViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
        mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
    }

    LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
        return mAllWords;
    }

    public void insert(Word word) {
        mRepository.insert(word);
    }
}
```

```
mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
                new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()))
                .get(WordViewModel.class);
```

```
public class WordRepository {

    private WordDao mWordDao;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

    public WordRepository(Application application) {

        WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mWordDao = db.wordDao();
        mAllWords = mWordDao.getAllWords();
    }

    LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
        return mAllWords;
    }

    public void insert(Word word) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mWordDao).execute(word);
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Word, Void, Void> {

        private WordDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertAsyncTask(WordDao dao) {
            mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Word... params) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract WordDao wordDao();

    private static WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {

        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback =
            new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onOpen(db);
                    new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();
                }
            };

    /**
     * Populate the database in the background.
     */
    private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final WordDao mDao;
        String[] words = {"dolphin", "crocodile", "cobra"};

        PopulateDbAsync(WordRoomDatabase db) {
            mDao = db.wordDao();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            // Start the app with a clean database every time.
            // Not needed if you only populate the database
            // when it is first created
            mDao.deleteAll();

            for (int i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
                Word word = new Word(words[i]);
                mDao.insert(word);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to instantiate ViewModel class in my MainActivity's **onCreate** method but it shows the following error.

**Cannot create an instance of class com.example.roomwords_sample.WordViewModel**

I also tried using **ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class)** but it is still showing the same error. I also looking at other people's answers on similar question but it is not working. I have tried almost everything. Kindly help me out.

Added stack trace

```
2020-09-20 01:51:37.103 13578-13578/com.example.roomwords_sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.roomwords_sample, PID: 13578
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.roomwords_sample/com.example.roomwords_sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.roomwords_sample.WordViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.roomwords_sample.WordViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.roomwords_sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.roomwords_sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.roomwords_sample.WordDao com.example.roomwords_sample.WordRoomDatabase.wordDao()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.roomwords_sample.WordRepository.<init>(WordRepository.java:18)
        at com.example.roomwords_sample.WordViewModel.<init>(WordViewModel.java:18)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.roomwords_sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace

Comment: Added Sir... but it says it needs to be verified by trusted community members first

Comment: The 'Caused by' line notes exactly what the error is: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.roomwords_sample.WordDao com.example.roomwords_sample.WordRoomDatabase.wordDao()' on a null object reference at com.example.roomwords_sample.WordRepository.<init>(WordRepository.java:18)` - it has nothing to do with your ViewModel and everything to do with your `WordRepository`. Can you include that class as well?

Comment: Yes I have added Respository class

Comment: So why is `WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)` returning null? Can you include *that* code?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have added the code for RoomDatabase class as well. I think all the problem is with the ViewModel instantiation. Since it is deprecated, I can't find the right way to do it. I have checked other questions, even different Youtube Tutorials. All the solutions they just, they just don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)` method

When you write:

```
if (INSTANCE == null) {
    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
        WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
        .build();
}
```

You create the database, but you don't actually assign it to your `INSTANCE` variable. That means your `INSTANCE` is **always** null and `WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)` never actually returns anything but null.

You can fix your issue and the `NullPointerException` that comes from it by setting your `INSTANCE` variable:

```
if (INSTANCE == null) {
    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
        WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
        .build();
}
```